# Why doesn't this positive lookbehind work?

Tags: java, regex, lookbehind

I have this string (which is just the cut out part of a larger string):

```
00777: 50.000 bit/s
```

and want to capture the 50.000 bit/s part
I've created a positive look-behind regex like this:

```
(?<=\d{5}: )\S+\s+\S+
```

Which works but when there are more spaces between the : and the number it doesn't - like expected.

So I did this:

```
(?<=\d{5}:\s+)\S+\s+\S+
```

But that doesn't work?! Why? Even this expression doesn't match any string:

```
(?<=\d{0,5}).*
```

What is it that I'm missing here?

Comment: Isn't this a positive look behind ?

Comment: `(?<=...)` is positive look behind. Some regular expression engines does not support (positive/negative) look behind.

Comment: First, you are using positive look-behind, not look-ahead. Secondly, there are a very few regex engines that support variable length look-behinds. Which one are you using?

Comment: you're right - it is!

Comment: For my testing I'm using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ but i want this implemented in Java

Comment: @esper, Java supports variable length lookbehinds, but your testing site does not.

Comment: @Qtax. No, Java doesn't support variable length look-behinds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because many regex engines don't support quantifiers(`+`,`*`,`?`) in lookbehind.

Example:`java`,`javascript`

**EDIT**

Since you are using Java,you can use group

```
Matcher m=Pattern.compile("\\d{5}:\\s+(\\S+\\s+\\S+)").matcher(input);
if(m.find())
  value=m.group(1);
```

Comment: Actually, you've answered it with the first line. Java code is just a cherry at the top

Answer (score 0):

In the first one you can use a variable amount of spaces with `(?<=\d{5}: +)`, but like the other answer, it might not be supported by your regex engine.

The last expression doesn't match any string because of the `.` on the data, it's not part of the `\d` char class, you could use `[\d\.]`

As a rule of thumb, I always start writing the simplest regex that will do it and I rely on data patterns that I believe will stay.

If you expect the unit to always be after the number you're after, and it will always be `bit/s`, there's no reason not to include it as a literal in your regex:

```
[\d\.]+ bit/s$
```

Then you can start to turn it into a more complex expression if you find exceptions in your data, like a unit with kbit/s:

```
(<value>[\d\.]+) *(<unit>\w+)/s$
```

Using [named capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) so it's easier and more readable to reference them later so can multiply the value by the unit, etc.

In resume: don't use fancier features if you won't really need them.